# Downloading Video doesnt work, streaming does

Tags: c#, stream, download, downloadfileasync

The code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += t_ProgressChanged;
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://cdn3.streamcloud.eu:8080/6hv75ivjnkoax3ptx3silq7q6hn4jq324yv5gophqq4eq7fqqglgw5kneq/video.mp4"), @"c:\video.mp4");
```

isn't realy working fro me. Even if I wait several minutes the file doesn't appear in the folder. 
I'm able to stream the file in a windows media player but not to download it.

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sems like I have fixed my problem.
I had to write the filename instead of the path+filename.
It downloaded the file into the folder of the programm.